# How to get Facebook friends of friends male/female ratio

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to get the Facebook friends of friends male/female ratio for my app. I know, there is no way to get the friends of friends list via the API. But I just need to get friends of friends male/female ratio or male and friends of friends female count.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to check a user's gender without their uid, and you won't be able to get friends-of-friends' uids - so no, unfortunately not